# Bring back Country Name from an excel string

Tags: excel, split, country

I have an excel sheet that I have a field called Address which contains full address for a list of customers, I need to bring out the Country Name from this field only. I have a list of countries from the internet I can use to search for but need a formula to bring back the country in a separate column.

**Example of data:**

```
E2: 0061 The Masters, South Africa
E3: 1 Exiter place, Upper Union Street, St Peter Port, Guernsey, GX1 YLB
```

As you can see the country isn't always in the same space.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This will be difficult to achieve using only Excel.  Typically, your problem would be handled by a web service such as Google Geocoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have list of countries in `Sheet1` as:

[image]

and your data is in `Sheet2`. Try the following **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$12,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(Sheet1!A$1:A$12,E2)),0)),"")
```

Copy/drag this formula down as required.

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Got this formula from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914150/excel-country-code/28915035#28915035) by @TomSharpe

Comment: Use search instead of find

Comment: @zaptask - Any particular reason behind using find?

Comment: Thanks for the credits ;-) Yes although you would expect countries to have a capital letter, it's probably better to use SEARCH so it matches south africa etc. Arguably it needs a second list to map territories like Guernsey (and even England, Wales etc.) into countries like UK.

Comment: @TomSharpe - Exactly, so its up to the OP now to manage the list of countries.

Comment: @JoelG - You are welcome. Best of luck with your project.